# Why is my scheduled task only starting when I open the Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I created a scheduled task in the Windows Task Scheduler (W10). It triggers on startup (or log in of any user, I am flexible there) and launches a .bat file.

The task runs with the privileges of user A, who has admin rights. The task should run under any user though, mainly user B, who does not have admin rights.

I cannot get it to work properly, the task does not start automatically. Here is the setup:
[image: Task settings 1]
[image: Task settings 2]
[image: Task settings 3]
[image: Task settings 4]
[image: Task settings 5]

What happens, is that I reboot the PC, log in as user B, and check if the task is running. I do that by opening a browser and connecting to a localhost address, which is unreachable -> the task is not running.

I now open the Task Scheduler, as user A, because under user B my task is not listed, since it was created under user A. I look at the list, and I see the task is running. Hm, I go to my browser again, refresh, and tadaa it works.

I specifically rebooted again and re-did all the steps, and checked the browser after each one. The conclusion is, the task starts ONLY once I open the task list in the Task Scheduler, not before. I tried adding a one minute delay to the start, but even after waiting 10 minutes, the task does not start. But as soon as I open the task list in the Scheduler - there it runs.

Does anyone know why?

EDIT: Here are the contents of the bat file:

```
REM @echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Retrive the application home
for %%F in ("%~f0") do set AGENT_BASE=%%~dpF
set AGENT_BASE=%AGENT_BASE%..
set APP_BASE=%AGENT_BASE%

echo %AGENT_BASE%

CALL "%AGENT_BASE%\config\setenv.bat"
SET JAVA_EXE="%APP_BASE%\java\%JAVA_VERSION%\bin\java"

%JAVA_EXE% -Duser.dir="%AGENT_BASE%" -jar "%AGENT_BASE%\%EXEC_JAR%" 
pause
```

The mentioned setenv.bat contains this:

```
set JAVA_VERSION=11.0.4.11
set EXEC_JAR=runtime\1.0.41\quarkus-run.jar
```

Comment: With the task selected, check the History tab and see if the task actually tries to start earlier, or if there are any errors? You might want to check if the task scheduler service is running and Automatic. If it's not too long, can you add the contents of that .bat file to your question?

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I added the bat contents to the question.
Also checked the History, and there is one try, and it has no error. But is is indeed earlier, namingly at the timestamp where I log on. Except it does not actually start at that time, only when I look at it. Kinda like quantum physics.
The scheduler service is also set as automatic and running, right after rebooting.

Comment: @Reygok3 When showing a task, it's cleaner to export the task in Task Scheduler, open the export in a text editor, then copy/paste the XML content within a code box

Comment: 1) You should not have a `pause` in your batch script (the task will be "running" forever), and it would be a good idea to add some basic logging like `echo %AGENT_BASE% >> c:\temp\mytask.log` to see which command it sits on. 2) Can you check whether the java process starts when the task does? some other way like task manager. 3) does the webservice launch if you start some other program like notepad **as** user A? I've seen some java apps behave weirdly with user sessions, but idk what it would be waiting on here. Maybe quarkus has a log that might say

Comment: Will try those when I have time, thanks.